# How to prove that these vectors are linearly independent?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, functional-equations

Consider the following vectors:

$v_m = (f(ma_1), f(ma_2), \dots, f(ma_n))$ for $m \in \{1,\dots, n\}$,

where $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous, strictly monotonic, and nonlinear function and $a_1 \neq a_2 \neq \dots a_n$ take values in $\mathbb{R}$. Can we prove that *there exist* $a_1, \dots a_n$ such that $v_1, \dots, v_n$ are linearly independent? We can put additional costraints on $f$ if necessary.

I tried to show that for $n = 2$ by putting the following constraint on $f$: there exist $x$ and $y$ such that

$\frac{f(x)}{f(y)} \neq \frac{f(2x)}{f(2y)}.$

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3315920/what-are-all-the-functions-that-satisfy-fx-fy-fkx-fky/3315974#3315974) for the types of functions that satisfy $\frac{f(x)}{f(y)} = \frac{f(kx)}{f(ky)}.$

Now, we can do a proof by contradiction. Suppose that for all $a_1 \neq a_2$, $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly dependent. We can write

$v_1 = k v_2  \Rightarrow (f(a_1), f(a_2)) = (kf(2a_1), kf(2a_2))$.

Therefore, we have

$\frac{f(a_1)}{f(a_2)} = \frac{f(2a_1)}{f(2a_2)}$ for all $a_1, a_2$,

which contradicts our assumption.

Is it possible to derive something similar for $n > 2$?

I tried the following. Suppose that $v_1, \dots, v_n$ are linearly dependent. Then there exist $k_1, \dots k_n$ such that the following equations

$k_1 f(a_m) + k_2 f(2a_m) + \dots + k_{n-1} f((n-1)a_m) =  f(na_m)$ for $m \in \{1, \dots, n\}$,

are satisfied for any choice of $a_1, \dots, a_n$. Can we say that the following condition for $f(x)$ is sufficient for linear independence of $v_1, \dots, v_n$? If so, what functions satisfy this property?

Condition on $f$: We cannot find any set of values for $k_1, \dots, k_{n-1}$ such that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$

$k_1 f(x) + k_2 f(2x) + \dots + k_{n-1} f((n-1)x) =  f(nx)$.